# How to overlay 2 canvas in React?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, chart.js

I have a basic chart using React and Chart.js. 
I want to overlay another canvas over the chart and keep both canvas of the same size.

This Chart.js library uses canvas under hood. Now the chart is fine, and it uses react-chartjs-2 package (react wrapper for chart.js).

Here is the code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wz0m8915kk)

1.I don't quite understand the nature of canvas in React. How it works. 
How to make both canvas - chart and layer of the size of container. In plain CSS it is something like position:absolute width 100% height 100% but here I cant apply these rules directly to canvas itself.

2.Is it fine to use refs and updates of local state to work with canvas, like I do in this example?